# TypeError: object takes no parameters

Tags: python, loops, iterator, generator, yield

I'm trying to create a code that utilizes the `__iter__()` method as a generator, but I am getting an error saying:

> TypeError: object() takes no parameters.

Additionally, I am unsure whether my yield function should be called within try: or within the `main()` function

I am fairly new to Python and coding, so any suggestions and advice would be greatly appreciated so that I can learn. Thanks!

```
class Counter(object):

    def __init__(self, filename, characters):
        self._characters = characters
        self.index = -1

        self.list = []
        f = open(filename, 'r')
        for word in f.read().split():
            n = word.strip('!?.,;:()$%')
            n_r = n.rstrip()
            if len(n) == self._characters:
                self.list.append(n)

    def __iter(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        try:
            self.index += 1
            yield self.list[self.index]

            except IndexError:
                raise StopIteration
            f.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for word in Counter('agency.txt', 11):
        print "%s' " % word
```

Comment: Please include the Traceback of the error, it helps.

Comment: ...your `__init` etc. methods lack two underscores at the end. It's `__init__`. That might cause the error.

Comment: And also indented too far.

Comment: The indentation and forgotten __init__ underscored were the issue! Thank you all so much for helping me with my silly typos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `yield` for function `__iter__`:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, count):
        self.count = count

    def __iter__(self):
        for i in range(self.count):
            yield i

for i in A(10):
    print i
```

In your case, `__iter__` maybe looks something like this:

```
def __iter__(self):
    for i in self.list:
        yield i
```

Answer (score 0):

You mistyped the declaration of the `__init__` method, you typed:

```
def __init
```

Instead of:

```
def __init__
```

Comment: Oh wow, I can't believe I missed that. Glad that that issue was just a dumb typo, however, now the error is telling me: TypeError: 'Counter' object is not iterable. Thoughts?

Comment: @D.Lopez Same thing for `def __iter__`